# Getting a "self signed certificate in certificate chain" while installing ElectronJS

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am trying to install electron JS using npm and getting this error. Is there a way to fix it? I have tried using the following configs which I saw in some other posts but they are not working for me:
`npm config set strict-ssl false --global`
`npm config set ca null`.
Following is the screenshot[image]